# Adding a WCF Data Service reference to another WCF Data Service

Tags: proxy, odata, wcf-data-services

We currently have two different applications consuming our OData, WCF Data Service

We want to add a third application, but this one, rather than being a website, is another WCF Data Service.  It is effectively a subset of functionality, exposing some methods from the internal service to as a public api.

As soon as I add a reference from one WCF Data Service to another, I end up in a conflict between System.Data.Services in the GAC and Microsoft.Data.Services implementations of DataService.

Is there a proper way to create an OData WCF Data Service wrapper for another OData WCF Service?

This is the error

> Error 1   Reference.datasvcmap: The type
>   'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1' is ambiguous: it
>   could come from assembly 'D:\source...\bin\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.DLL' or from
>   assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services.Client\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.Client.dll'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type
>   name. App_WebReferences/WcfDataService/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it has to do with the wrapping (may just be a side-effect from the way you set it up in Visual Studio). Try removing the reference to `System.Data.Services.Client.dll`, I believe the OOB NuGet packages are favored.